# Joint PMF of 3 Discrete RVs

Tags: statistics, random-variables, independence

I have 3 joint PMF $(X,Y,Z)$ respectively as follow:

$(0,0,1)$

$(0,1,0)$

$(1,0,0)$

$(1,1,1)$

Each with $p = 1/4$

I am asked to compute the $COV(X,Y), V(X+Y)$ and find out whether only $X,Y$ are independent or $X,Y,Z$ are all independent

My problem is I do not know how to extract $X,Y$ from those $4$ points since $Z$ always stick around. I can do this problem with joint PMF of 2 RVs. I have looked around but can't see any similar problem such as Joint PMF of more than $2$ RVs. Also, i don't know how to deal with independence of $X,Y,Z$ once at a time

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Outcome space is $\Omega=\{(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,1)\}$.

$\sigma$-algebra is the powerset of $\Omega$.

Probability measure $P$ on $\langle\Omega,\wp(\Omega)\rangle$ is prescribed by $A\mapsto\frac14|A|$ for $A\in\wp(\Omega)$ so that $P(\{\omega\})=\frac14$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$.

We have the following random variables:

$X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is prescribed by $(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3)\mapsto\omega_1$

$Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is prescribed by $(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3)\mapsto\omega_2$

$Z:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is prescribed by $(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3)\mapsto\omega_3$

Now everything is well modeled and we can start.

E.g. we can find $\mathbb EXY$ by stating that $$\mathbb EXY=\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}X(\omega)Y(\omega)P(\{\omega\})=\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}\omega_1\omega_2\frac14=[0\cdot0+0\cdot1+1\cdot0+1\cdot1]\frac14=\frac14$$

I leave the rest to you.

Comment: I have calculated everything down and get X and Y are independent. So does it mean that in this problem. Cov(X,Y) = Var(X,Y) = 0 and they are uncorrelated ? If it is not then I guess I get my computing process incorrectly

Comment: Indeed $X$ and $Y$ are independent here, and independence implies that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, i.e. that the covariance takes value $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also (should have) said that V(X+ Y) = 0. Is it also the case whenever Cov(X,Y) =0? or it does not have to necessarily be?

Comment: If $V$ stands for variance (as I expect) then the answer is:"no". It is definitely not $0$. In general $V(X,Y)=V(X)+2Cov (X,Y)+V(Y)$. So if the covariance is $0$ then the midle term falls away.

Comment: Thanks for waking me up, otherwise I would think that V(X+Y) is always 0 whenever Cov(X,Y) is 0. But actually in this case, I have calculated things down and V(X+Y) is also 0. Thanks again :):)

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

To find $P(X=x, Y=y)$, you can sum up the $z$ variables:

$$P(X=x, Y=y)= \sum_{z} P(X=x, Y=y, Z=z)$$

Similarly,

$$P(X=x)= \sum_{y,z} P(X=x, Y=y, Z=z)$$

For example, $P(X=0)=p(0,0,1)+p(0,1,0)=\frac12$

Intuitively for independence of the $3$ random variables, think of whether having $2$ of them give u information about the third.

Comment: By doing some calculations (by using the example you gave me), I get P(X=x, Y=y) = P(X=x)P(Y=y) and conclude that X,Y are independent (and also do the same for all X,Y,Z). However, I am still not really get the point ''whether having 2 of them give u information about the third''. Could you please clarify little bit more ? Thank you :)

Comment: If I tell you $X$ and $Y$, do you what is $Z$? You are right that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. check your working for $3$ variables.

Comment: I have done calculation and concluded that X,Y,Z are not independent. You mean that if i know X = 0, Y = 0, do i know Z = 1 ? This is also equivalent to the question that i should ask myself if i were given X = 0, Y = 0 and a p=1/4. Can i do something to get Z? I think yes because i have showed that they are all not independent. But i am still unsure..

Comment: $\neg Z = X \oplus Y$. $Z$ is the negation of [exlusion or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: may I get exact value of Z by doing some calculation in this particular case ?(assuming I only know X,Y and p=1/4)

Comment: For this particular question, if you know $X$ and $Y$, you know the value of $Z$ using the formula that I provided.  If you know the value of $X=0$, $Y=0$ you know $Z=1$ for sure,